# Nginx 502 FastCGI Error

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

When I try to access a certain page on my server, it returns with a 502 Gateway error. (Sometimes it works but then I reload the page and it shows the 502 Gateway page again).

If I check the nginx error logs, this error comes up:

```
2017/09/13 19:14:49 [error] 3762#3762: *22 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: serverip, server: localhost, request: "GET /inventory.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "localhost"
```

I tried looking up the error on google, but no solutions so far, and was wondering if someone knows what the error is & how to fix it.

Thanks.

## Edit 1:

- fastcgi_buffers are set to this:

fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;

fastcgi_buffer_size 120k;

Comment: How dynamic is this page? i.e, is it possible php is running into an error and closing stdout on only some requests?

Answer (score 2):

I used below code in my nginx configuration and reload nginx, solved my issue -

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 120k;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase values of the next settings:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size
fastcgi_buffers
```

https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffer_size
https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffers

Comment: I increased them, restarted nginx but still throws the 502 error. Any idea how far i should increase them? Added an edit to the original post.

Comment: Depends on what size of the fastcgi answer. Also you should look at the php error log.